# Git push over ssh fails using remote url instead of origin name - (ERROR: Repository not found)

Tags: git, github, ssh

Hi I have setup Git/Github with SSH successfully. I know this because I went through the [Github help guide](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) to check this and all results passed OK.

I can push to my Github repo using the following command for a tag example:

```
git push origin <tagname>
```

However, when I try to do the same thing but specify the remote by url, it fails telling me that the repo does not exist:

```
git push git@github.com:<organisationname>/<reporname>.git <tagname>
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

The [documentation for git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) does support both syntax so I'm stumped as to why the URL version fails and the "origin" version does not?

Comment: Works fine for me, did you maybe mistype somewhere?

Comment: Well its actually sytnax I'm getting from a maven release build that fails to push the release tag. So I was just taking the line from the stack trace and running it manually to make sure that it was nothing to do with the release plugin. Long story short, I assumed that there were no typos.

Comment: I'll double check the syntax now though

Comment: Maybe the maven release plugin does not use the commandline Git client but something like jgit and that library does not support this syntax?

Comment: Did you try to add a remote? `git remote add another-origin git@github.com:<organisationname>/<reporname>.git` and `git push another-origin <tagname>`

Comment: no not tried that, but i'm not sure what it would achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and it was actually a simple one. The user configured for the release plugin was different to the user configured for access to the repos. In my question I have an example including "git" as the user, which actually did not represent the URL used by the maven plugin, it was using a different user.

So for clarity, if ssh access was based on "user1" and maven release plugin was configured to run with "user2" then that's when I get the failed push.

To handle this in a user ambiguous way the git docs suggests always pushing using the "git" user.

For example, even with an ssh key setup for "user1", in my setup the following push was still successful:

```
git push git@github.com:<organisationname>/<reporname>.git <tagname>
```

But the following is not:

```
git push user2@github.com:<organisationname>/<reporname>.git <tagname>
```

Now I know the reason, its pretty obvious and feels silly that I missed that in my config originally. This also explains why the original question if run on any repo setup with proper ssh keys works fine, as the comments suggest.